# How do I create a parameterised type from a macro?

Tags: templates, generics, rust

I have a macro that creates a struct and a heap of supporting functions and trait implementations. The interesting bit for this question is:

```
macro_rules! make_struct {
    ($name: ident) => {
        struct $name;
    }
}
```

This works as you'd expect:

```
make_struct!(MyStruct);
```

If I want to make a parameterised type however, I'm out of luck:

```
make_struct!(AnotherStruct<T: SomeTrait>);

test.rs:8:27: 8:28 error: no rules expected the token `<`
test.rs:8 make_struct!(AnotherStruct<T: SomeTrait>);
```

The name of the struct is an `ident` so I can't just change that in the macro args (eg to `ty`):

```
test.rs:3:16: 3:21 error: expected ident, found `MyStruct`
test.rs:3         struct $name;
```

So how do I write this macro to be able to handle both? Or do I need to separate ones? In the latter case, what does the macro look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the keyword `struct`, the parser expects a ident token tree, which may be followed by `<` and more; ty is definitely not what it wants (as an example of why it wouldn’t work, `(Trait + Send + 'static)` is a valid ty, but `struct (Trait + Send + 'static);` clearly doesn’t make sense).

To support generics, you will need to produce more rules.

```rust
macro_rules! make_struct {
    ($name:ident) => {
        struct $name;
    };
    ($name:ident<$($t:ident: $constraint:ident),+>) => {
        struct $name<$($t: $constraint),+>;
    }
}
```

As you doubtless observe, making it support everything that the parser would accept in that location is nigh impossible; macro_rules isn’t that clever. There is, however, this one weird trick (static code analysers hate it!) which allows you to take a sequence of token trees and treat it as a normal `struct` definition. It uses just a little bit more of indirection with macro_rules:

```rust
macro_rules! item {
    ($item:item) => ($item);
}
macro_rules! make_struct {
    ($name:ident) => {
        struct $name;
    };
    ($name:ident<$($tt:tt)*) => {
        item!(struct $name<$($tt)*;);
    };
}
```

Note that due to overzealousness, `ident` doesn’t currently allow sequence repetition (`$(…)`) to immediately follow it, so you’ll be stuck putting some token tree between the `ident` and the repetition, e.g. `$name:ident, $($tt:tt)*` (yielding `AnotherStruct, <T: SomeTrait>`) or `$name:ident<$(tt:tt)*` => `struct $name<$($tt)*;`. The value of this is reduced by the fact that you can’t pull it apart quite so easily to get at the individual generic types, which you will need to do for things like inserting `PhantomData` markers.

You may find it helpful to passing the entire `struct` item; it passes as the `item` type (just like a `fn`, `enum`, `use`, `trait`, *&c.* would do).